# Content in UIButton moving after animation

Tags: ios, cocoa, animation, uibutton, frame

I'm having an issue with my `UIButton` after my animation. Let me explain the step.

I've one button, with an image inside. When I tap on my button, I animate the frame to get a large width and then when my frame got the right size I add my text (so there is my image on the left and text on the right).
First when I begin the animation my image is completely to the left and I don't know why, and when I go back to the initial frame, my image is totally away of my `UIButton`, still don't know why :(

There is some screen to more explication :

http://pastebin.com/6MQ5xyA8 (sorry I can't paste more than one link without 10 points reputation)

And this is my code :

```
// Extand
CGRect loginSize = self.nvButtonConnect.frame;
loginSize.size.width = 297;
loginSize.size.height = 48;
CABasicAnimation *sizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
sizeAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.nvButtonConnect.frame];
sizeAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:loginSize];
[sizeAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
sizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

// Go back (in another method)
CGRect loginSize = self.nvButtonConnect.frame;
loginSize.size.width = 48;
loginSize.size.height = 48;
CABasicAnimation *sizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
sizeAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.nvButtonConnect.frame];
sizeAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:loginSize];
[sizeAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
sizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

Have you any idea?
I try with custom contentEdgeInset, TitleEdgeInset, ImageEdgeInset, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a `CABasicAnimation` instead of a regular animation block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `frame` value to your `bounds`, which is displacing the origin of the view's coordinate system. Use `bounds` consistently and it should work.